# A service failed in the ‘onPrepare’ hook

Tags: webdriver-io, appium-android

I am running Android app test cases using Appium and WebDriverIO. I am encountering the following error:

```
Execution of 1 workers started at 2024-02-26T10:08:46.718Z

2024-02-26T10:08:47.749Z ERROR @wdio/appium-service: info

2024-02-26T10:08:47.750Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: info
    at Socket.<anonymous> (file:///home/runner/work/e2e-tests/node_modules/@wdio/appium-service/build/launcher.js:172:28)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)

    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
Continue...
```

### Dependencies

```
"@wdio/allure-reporter": "^8.32.2",
   "@wdio/appium-service": "^8.32.3",
   "@wdio/cli": "^8.32.3",
   "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.32.3",
   "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.32.3",
   "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.32.2",
   "appium": "^2.5.1",
    "appium-uiautomator2-driver": "^3.0.1"
```

**Config file**

```
const path = require('path');
exports.config = {

    runner: 'local',
    specs: [],
    exclude: [],
    maxInstances: 10,
    capabilities: {
        phone1: {
            port: 4442,
            path: '/',
            capabilities: {
                platformName: 'android',
                'appium:automationName': 'uiautomator2',
                'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel 3a',
                'appium:platformVersion': '14',
                'appium:udid': 'emulator-5554',
                'appium:adbExecTimeout': 50000,
                'appium:noReset': false,
                'appium:dontStopAppOnReset': true,
                'appium:fullReset': false,
                'appium:systemPort': 8200,
                'appium:appWaitDuration': '2000000',
                'appium:app': path.join(process.cwd(), '../app/build/outputs/apk/debug.apk'),
                'appium:autoGrantPermissions': true,
                'appium:uiautomator2ToastWaitTimeout': 7000,
                'appium:waitforTimeout': 30000,
                'appium:newCommandTimeout': 600
            }
        }
    },

    logLevel: 'error',
    bail: 0,
    baseUrl: '',
    waitforTimeout: 100000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    services: [
        [
            'appium',
            {
                command: 'appium',
                args: {
                    port: 4442
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    framework: 'mocha',
    watch: true,
    reporters: [
        [
            'allure',
            {
                outputDir: 'allure-results',
                disableWebdriverStepsReporting: true,
                disableWebdriverScreenshotsReporting: false
            }
        ]
    ],
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 600000
    },
    afterTest: async function (test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
        if (error !== undefined) {
            await phone1.takeScreenshot();
        }
    }
};
```

After receiving this error, the test case runs completely fine. I don't understand why it's being displayed as an error instead of just info.
`Error: info at Socket.<anonymous>`

Can someone help me resolve this error?

**More information:**
This only happened the first time after installing the project, when I tried it again it worked fine.